# itextsharp 4.1.6 gridview backcolor

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, itext

Good day,

Ive been working with itextsharp 4.1.6 and i am trying to export an html page to PDF.
I am able to do this, but then styling on the table is lost.

I'm not doing allot to it. All i need is the first line/header row of the gridview to be shaded.
I have the source code, but then i am not sure what to add were to allow the back color to be printed to PDF.

Does anyone have the dll that contains this already or the code that i will need to add to the source to allow this?

Comment: css is not working when you used html to pdf create custom pdf. and use newer version of iTextshatp.

Comment: Due to the licensing of the latest version of iTextSharp, i cannot use it. Anyway i was able to find a useful solution to doing what i needed to do.

Comment: I'm in no means a legal expert but there is a myth about the old licensing model (2.1.7/4.1.6) being "free". I encourage you to check out the author's post on the subject here. http://www.lowagie.com/license

Comment: Can you post a simple sample? iTextSharp has no knowledge of ASP.Net or GridViews so it would help if you didn't post that and only the actual (abbreviated) rendered HTML.